# Approximation using a Fourier transform with low pass filter

Tags: fourier-transform, lowpass-filter

I need to approximate a function f, but I cannot do so with frequencies that exceed 1kHz

What is the best approximation I can get? Is taking the Fourier transform then zeroing any term above 1kHz the best approximation? Or can I fiddle with the lower order terms and get a better fit?

This is a made up scenario, but I have to prove the same concept with Walsh transforms. I am fairly certain that the lower order terms form the best approximation from random twiddling and hill climbing searches, but I need proof.

I believe the proof is something very similar to a least squares regression proof, but I can't get it. Has this problem been solved before? At least in the Fourier domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by 'best'.  In terms of least squares, then yes, just knocking off the terms above 1kHz will give the closest approximation.  I guess one way to prove it would be:
$$
     x(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(f)\exp\left( j2\pi ft \right) dt\\
\hat x(t) = \int_{-1k}^{1k} X(f)        \exp\left( j2\pi ft \right) dt
$$
leaving a residual error of
$$
e(t) = \int_{|f| > 1k} X(f)\exp\left( j2\pi ft \right) dt .
$$

Compare this to a 'fiddled' version, using $\tilde X(f)$ for the coefficients:
$$
\hat x(t) = \int_{-1k}^{1k} \tilde X(f) \exp\left( j2\pi ft \right) dt,
$$
which has a residual error of
$$
e(t) = \int_{|f| \le 1k} \left(X(f) - \tilde X(f)\right) \exp\left( j2\pi ft \right) dt + 
\int_{|f| > 1k} X(f)\exp\left( j2\pi ft \right) dt ,
$$
which is greater than the error in the first instance unless $\tilde X(f) = X(f) \; \forall f$.

Something like that ought to do it, anyway.

EDIT: It is possible to prove that a projection onto any orthogonal set of functions (doesn't need to be the Fourier set) gives the least squares fit:

$$
\int f_k(t) f_m(t) dt = \cases{
  0, & $k \ne m$ \\
  1/\lambda_k, & $k = m$}
$$
for any orthogonal basis set $\{f_k\}$ (I'm not bothering with weighting functions), where
$$
\lambda_k = \frac{1}{\int f^2(t) dt}
$$
The projection of $g(t)$ onto the set is given by
$$
c_k = \lambda_k \int g(t)f_k(t) dt.
$$
The least squares fit of a set of orthogonal basis function is the minimisation of
$$
\int \left[g(t) - \sum_k d_k f_k(t)\right]^2 dt.
$$
Minimise by setting the derivative (wrt $d_m$) to zero:
$$
2\int\left(g(t) - \sum_kd_kf_k(t)\right)\left(-f_m(t)\right) dt = 0 \\
-\int f_m(t)g(t)dt + \int f_m(t)\sum_kd_kf_k(t)dt = 0 \\
-\int f_m(t)g(t)dt + \sum_kd_k \int f_m(t)f_k(t)dt = 0 \\
-\int f_m(t)g(t)dt + \sum_kd_k \frac{1}{\lambda_m} = 0
$$
which rearranges to give the same value as for $c_k$, thus the least squares fit is exactly the straightforward projection onto the orthogonal set.

Comment: Thank you. I had something like this floating in pieces. I had an idea that the orthogonality was going to be an important part of it. This answer is awesome. Thank you so much for the extra detail